# How to display dropbox download url after upload from custom Android app

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am creating an Android app which will allow users to upload video files to dropbox. I want the app to display a pop up message when the upload has completed which shows the user the URL to re-download their file. I'm using the Dropbox API V2 but I can't find anything relating to this.  Looking online I can find mentions of using "share" but they seem to be related to an earlier version of the SDK.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way of getting a file's data from the Dropbox API is by directly downloading the data from a file download endpoint, and not by returning a URL the user can access. In the Dropbox API v2 Java SDK, you can use the [`downloadBuilder`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v2.0.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/DbxFiles.html#downloadBuilder-java.lang.String-) method to get a [`DownloadBuilder`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v2.0.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/DbxFiles.DownloadBuilder.html) you can use to download the content.

If you do want to get a link, you can use [`createSharedLinkBuilder`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v2.0.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/DbxSharing.html#createSharedLinkBuilder-java.lang.String-), but that's only really intended for sharing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the purpose of the pop up message is so that the user can copy the URL of their file and then email it to somebody else to share their video.  It sounds as though the createSharedLinkBuilder may be best?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe before get an answer for this question, you need to clarify what kind of solution you are seeking for.

There are three kinds of potential solutions for this task.

(1) Using the Acitivties or Dialog provided by Dropbox SDK, you use Intent to interact with them and get response in onActivityResult() call.

(2) Using the libraries provided by Dropbox SDK and construct UI using you own code, in this case you use the object models (like Entry, Session and WebOAuth2Session, etc) and Helper classes to access the data.

(3) Construct the object models and network access helpers on HTTP/JSON according the Dropbox API to achieve a full control on cloud document access. the download URL you are looking for must be in the JSON response text.

Hope it can help you to get an answer quickly.